# Elasticsearch Groovy Script eachWithIndex

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

this is a groovy script. The problem is the **ctx._source.academies.remove(index)** because ctx is not visible there. The index variable is the right... but i cant use the ctx there. Any suggestions?

```
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.academies.eachWithIndex { it, index -> if(it['academy_id'] == academy_id) ctx._source.academies.remove(index) }",
    "params": {
        "academy_id": 344
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
ctx._source.academies.removeAll { it['academy_id'] == academy_id }
```

In case you need to check `academy_id` matching a list of items, then below can be used: (The closure should satisfy a criteria)

```
ctx._source.academies.removeAll { it['academy_id'] in [academy_id, some_other_id] }
```

From an elastic search perspective, I suppose the script can be rewritten as below:

```
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.academies.removeAll { it['academy_id'] in academy_ids }",
    "params": {
        "academy_ids": [344, 345, 346]
    }
}
```

Comment: You are perfect!!!!!! Thank you.... How can we make the academy_id array? Can we give to params the academies as array? So we can delete multiple academies with multiple ids at once

Comment: Yes of course. All you need is a boolean returning from closure. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

is this the best solution?

```
def findIndex; ctx._source.academies.eachWithIndex { it, index -> if(it['academy_id'] == academy_id) findIndex = index }; ctx._source.academies.remove(findIndex)
```

but this works only for the last found object