# Elasticsearch: How do I remove a nested object element?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 5.4, and attempting to remove an element from a nested datatype.

I have the following mapping:

```
"links_to_asset": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
        "note_link_id": {
            "type": "long"
        },
        "user_id": {
            "type": "long"
        },
        "creation": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
        },
        "modification": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "date_hour_minute_second"
        },
        "to_asset": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "from_asset": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "comment": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "std": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "asset_en_analyzer",
                    "fields": {
                        "std": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "standard"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried the following in Postman:

> localhost:9200/asset/bookmark/20976/_update?pretty

```
{
    "script": "ctx._source.links_to_asset.removeAll{it['note_link_id'] == id}",
    "params": {
        "id": 7343
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "remote_transport_exception",
                "reason": "[NvXYDwh][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "failed to execute script",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "script_exception",
            "reason": "compile error",
            "script_stack": [
                "... .links_to_asset.removeAll{it['links_to_asset.note_ ...",
                "                             ^---- HERE"
            ],
            "script": "ctx._source.links_to_asset.removeAll{it['links_to_asset.note_link_id'] == id}",
            "lang": "painless",
            "caused_by": {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "unexpected token ['{'] was expecting one of [{<EOF>, ';'}]."
            }
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

I've followed the advice in a couple of different questions here on StackOverflow [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38742217/630530) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39170510/630530), but with no success.

The nested object is valid, as I've populated it with data. Also, `id` value is valid, too.

Answer (score 2):

you trying to write a `groovy` script, but the scripting language you are using is `painless` in Elasticsearch 5.x

Try something like

```
ctx._source.foo = ctx._source.foo.stream().filter(x -> x =='a').collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Almost — it removes everything in the nested object, instead of the element with the ID in `params`: `ctx._source.links_to_asset = ctx._source.links_to_asset.stream().filter(x -> x =='a').collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @WayneSmallman then you could use
`params: ctx._source.links_to_asset = ctx._source.links_to_asset.stream().filter(x -> x.id != params.id).collect(Collectors.toList())`